# Does Row Locks still exist after a deadlock?

Tags: database, transactions, transaction-isolation, rowlocking

So In this image my teacher wrote in red that after the deadlock appeared the transaction1 is able to set x-lock and load the old data.

[image]

But after I tried it in SQL I have to wait because apparently the transaction2 still has seted the rowlock and a deadlock happens again.

So my question is, does (after a deadlock happened ) the row-locks still exist? Because apparently they don't in this case which my teacher provided.